# Static Variable problem On JQuery

Tags: jquery, variables, global

```
if(i==0){
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("div#rozet").hover(function(){
          $(this).hide("fast");
          $(this).animate(
                      { top:'+45px', left:'+500px'},
                      {duration: 1}
                      );        
         $(this).show("slow");           
         $(this).stopall();
        });
i=1;
}
if(i==1){
        $("div#rozet").hover(function(){
          $(this).hide("fast");
          $(this).animate(
                      { top:'-85px', left:'+500px'},
                      {duration: 1}
                      );        
         $(this).show("slow");           
         $(this).stopall();
        });
    });
i=0;
}
```

I'm sorry, I have a little English. Anyway I'm starting :D

I want to do this functions with queue. But i is always 0. I know I'm doing this. So what can I do :D

Can I take css's variables. (div#rozet).top's variable, I can use it on if

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an else if.  If you are calling a function that runs those two ifs, both will run if i == 0.  You can check it by putting an alert in each function.  When i is 0, the first if statement is true and does the work, and sets i to 1 and than the second if runs it now also is true since the last if set i to 1.

```
i = 0;
jQuery("#subheader").click(function () {
  if (i == 0) {
    alert ("i was 0");
    i = 1;
  }
  else if (i == 1) {
    alert ("i was 1");
    i = 0;
  }
});
```

This is the end result I created using Firebug.  If you have [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) you can run this in the console on this page.  Once it is run, you can click on the line that contains the number of answers and the sorting options.  I think that is roughly what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

where is i being declared and set?

BUT, you have your 
    if (i == 0)

before the 
    $(document).ready(function(){

That is a problem.  $(document).ready() is an event handler, so the code in $(document).ready() is being called, in spite of what i is equal to.

You have to rework your code so that

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if (i == 0) {
    ...
  }
  if (i == 1) {
    ...
  }

}
```